# ruby inserting hash into mongodb, getting undefined method `has_key?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, hash, insert, nosql

I am trying to insert hash into mongodb using ruby mongo driver. I get `undefined method has_key? error`

Below is the code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

include Mongo
@client = MongoClient.new('localhost', 27017)
@db     = @client['sample-db']
@coll   = @db['test1']

@coll.remove
puts abc
#value of abc hash is  {:command=>"runlocal", :remotecommand=>"rm process_2013-04-25.log"}

@coll.insert("#{abc}")
```

The output should look like

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5174c4aeb2441139ec000001"), "command" : "runlocal", "remotecommand" : "rm......" }
```

After looking at the forum i found a solution like below. But i dont want to change the schema.

```
id = @coll.insert({:status =>"#{abc}"})
```

Which produces

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("517b69d2b2441136b8000001"), "status" : "{'command' => "runlocal"....
```

**Update: solution**

```
 id = @coll.insert({"#{abc}"})
```

Which produces below output as needed

```
 {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('517bfc79b244110a08000001'), "command" : "runlocal", "remotecommand" : "rm process_2013-04-25.log"}
```

Comment: If `abc` is already a hash, why not directly use it as an argument as in `id = @coll.insert(abc)`?

Comment: i also tried using 

     id = @coll.insert({"#{abc}"})

which producses below output with the arrows which are not in json format

     {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('517bfc79b244110a08000001'), "command"=>"runlocal", "remotecommand"=>"rm process_2013-04-25.log"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: solution**

```
 id = @coll.insert({"#{abc}"})
```

which produces below output as needed

```
 {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('517bfc79b244110a08000001'), "command" : "runlocal", "remotecommand" : "rm process_2013-04-25.log"}
```